# Can I access the DI injector directly to instantiate classes with NestJS

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I am wondering if there is a way to access the DI injector in NestJS and use it directly to instantiate classes. This would be similar to how Angular or Inversify expose the injector directly for use in special cases.

Multi-providers would solve my use case. But until multi-providers are supported in NestJS, though, I am instead trying to create a composite guard that would tie several guards together as one so that I can globally apply several guards that need access to DI. I want the composite guard to receive only an array of types and then use the injector to fill out objects for those types.

I tried specifying `Injector` as a factory dependency, but Nest couldn't resolve it. And if it did resolve, I don't know how I would use the injector.

```
@Module({
    providers: [{
        provide: APP_GUARD,
        inject: [Injector],
        useFactory: (injector: Injector) => {
            return new MultiGuard([AuthGuard, PermissionGuard], injector);
        }
    }]
})
class AppModule {}
```

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Type } from '@nestjs/common';

export class MultiGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private readonly guards: Type<CanActivate>[],
        private readonly injector: Injector
    ) {}

    async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
        const guards = this.guards.map(guard => {
            return this.injector.get(guard);
        });

        const results = await Promise.all(guards);

        return results.every(r => !!r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar recently, but instead of passing types of guards to my "multiguard" I just instantiate the guards in a factory and pass an array of guard instances instead.

It's very similar to the way guards are executed by NestJS. Take a look at the `guard-consumer.ts` file.

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/core/guards/guards-consumer.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class GuardsCollection implements CanActivate {
  public constructor(private readonly guards: CanActivate[]) {}

  public async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    for (const guard of this.guards) {
      const result = guard.canActivate(context);
      if (!(await this.pickResult(result))) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  private async pickResult(result: boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean>): Promise<boolean> {
    if (result instanceof Observable) {
      return result.toPromise();
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

In the factory I instantiate my guards. If my guards have any dependencies I can resolve them there, by specifying the dependencies in the `Inject` array. The optional inject property accepts an array of providers that NestJS will resolve and pass as arguments to the factory function during the instantiation process.

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useFactory: (reflector: Reflector) => {
        return new GuardsCollection([
          new (AuthGuard('jwt'))(),
          new RolesGuard(reflector),
        ]);
      },
      inject: [Reflector],
    },
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Another possible option is to inject a `ModuleRef` and use it to resolve items within the context of the current module. You should also be able to get items from another module as long as that other module is imported into the current one.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyGlobalGuard implements CanActivate {
  public constructor(private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef) {}

  public async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    // ... resolve items.
    return true;
  }
}

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: GlobalGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```